# How to change text color depending on the stat of the element (focus,selected,hover)

Tags: jquery, colors, focus, hover, selected

I wan to change the color of an input element after it has been focused, the original color was grey, when I hover it becomes blue, same as when I focus, blue, after I check if the Form is valid, when there will be no email written, there's a jquery function that will change the background-color to red and color to white and change the value to some alert message, but when the user will click again on the input, that background-color will return to white, and I want the colors to return to normal, grey - blue (hover,selected or focused)

```
$("#email").focus ( function() { if(document.getElementById('email').style.backgroundColor=="Crimson") { $("#email").css("background-color","white");
                                            $("#email").css("color","grey");
                                                $("#email").css("font-weight","normal");
                                                $("#email").val(""); }});
```

Comment: its not clear what you want to do, can u please try to structure ur question and give a clear definition of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`css('background-color')` returns the colour in the format `rgb(r, g, b)`, so if you are setting it to `Crimson` then this code should fix your problem.

```
$("#email").focus(function() {
    if ($('#email').css('background-color') == "rgb(220, 20, 60)") {
        $("#email").css("background-color", "white");
        $("#email").css("color", "grey");
        $("#email").css("font-weight", "normal");
        $("#email").val("");
    }
});
```